# как добавить номер версии из commit msg в файл?

Tags: git, git-commit

Хочу сделать так, чтобы номер версии парсился из commit message и писался в исходный файл, при этом сохраняясь в репозитории.

написала post-commit hook со следующим содержимым:

```
grep -E "\[(\S+)\]" .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG > version
git commit --amend --no-verify
```

скрипт запускается, номер версии в файл пишется, а с повторным коммитом какая-то проблема:

```
$ git commit
Слишком много ошибок из стандартного потока вводафайлом... 
error: There was a problem with the editor 'editor'.
Пожалуйста, укажите сообщение, при указании опций -m или -F.
[1.0.4a2jen 46b9dad] [test666]
 3 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: проблема решена: параметр --no-verify пропускает только pre-commit и commit-msg скрипты, но не post-commit, из-за чего выполнение зацикливается. решение - "отключить" скрипт перед повторным коммитом:  chmod -x .git/hooks/post-commit git commit --amend --no-verify --no-edit chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit

Comment: какой ужас - менять права доступа при каждом вызове!  для временных флагов существуют переменные окружения

Answer (score 0):

Команде

```
git commit --amend --no-verify
```

нечего коммитить - в индекс ничего не добавлено,  изменения файла version добавлены только в рабочую папку

Comment: добавление git add version ничего не меняет